# How to enable Eclipse undo in a customized view

Tags: eclipse, move, undo

I have a customized view. I basically Move an element from one folder to another.
After Move i am setting the selection on the new element. Still the Eclipse Undo is not enabled. I expect it to come as "Undo Move Resources" as it happens in  Project Explorer.

Could anyone please tell what basically needs to be done for the "undo move resources" to be enabled? how does it work?

Regards,
Pavitra

Answer (score 0):

Undo seems not to be implemented in your customized view so there is no chance to enable it. You might ask the author to build this feature for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.undo.MoveResourcesOperation` class to perform a resource move operation with Undo. You use something like:

```java
AbstractWorkspaceOperation op = new MoveResourcesOperation(resources, destinationPath, "label");

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getOperationSupport()
                .getOperationHistory().execute(op, monitor,
                        WorkspaceUndoUtil.getUIInfoAdapter(messageShell));
```

You might be able to use `org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveResourceAction` which does all the work for this. See also `org.eclipse.ui.actions.MoveFilesAndFoldersOperation` and `org.eclipse.ui.actions.CopyFilesAndFoldersOperation`